# When to use std::complex<long double> vs. own complex data type (struct etc..)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, complex-numbers

I'm currently working on some project where the previous developer used

```
std::complex<long double>
```

throughout most of the code. The software relies heavily on methods from signal processing that were all implemented using the above complex data type.
Large multidimensional arrays are created, accessed, and deleted quite often.

The nice thing about this data type is, that all required mathematical functions (for example from `<cmath>` ) support complex numbers, so there is little overhead regarding basic mathematical operations with this data type.

Other functions, such as an n-dimensional complex convolution of large data volumes have been implemented in our software by said developer.

I currently work on an extension that uses the n-dimensional convolution A LOT. However most scenarios for this extension
**require no complex operations**.
The program currently runs quite slow and I'm wondering if it would be faster to use a proprietary struct in the critical parts. Sth like

```
struct CPLX{
long double REAL;
long double IMAG;
}CPLX;
```

and implement the required methods myself (implement mathematical operations such as complex multiplication, phase, etc...).

For the parts that do not require complex operations (which is true for most of my extension): wouldn't

`(a+0i)*(b+0i)`

be significantly slower than

`a*b`

?

**Will using an own struct with efficiently implemented mathematical operations and minimal overhead VS. using `std::complex` and `cmath` be faster?**
(Besides the fact that this would require additional testing to make sure everything works correctly)

**Is there a significant overhead when using `std::complex`?**
If so, when would the use of `std::complex` be more appropriate than the use of own methods and a struct?

Comment: I can't see how using your own struct would help at all. But why don't you implement your "efficient" mathematical functions using `std::complex`?

Comment: If you want speed implementing it yourself is exactly the wrong way to go. Look for the Intel, AMD or Nvidia math libraries which implement hand optimized assembly with cache blocking, parallel computation and SSE4.

Comment: This is too broad. Different implementations of std::complex will have different overheads and especially on different compilers with different inline abilities.

Comment: Another useful suggestion is that you may not need to use `long double`. Instead, carefully examine your floating point operations with a view to reduce error accumulation. You might also look into what I think is called linear float expressions. This is where you get more precision by expressing values as a summation like `2.5*10^9 + 3.7*10^3`

Comment: But the part that I'm working on doesn't require complex operations for most parts.. and the other parts that do can be handled separately. So wouldn't it be faster to use separate methods for the calculation? Why use the full blown complex operations (especially in an n-dim convolution where there are a lot of multiplications and additions?)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***DON'T REINVENT THE WHEEL***

The builtin standard libraries are already optimized and tuned for your hardware.  Don't waste your time trying to make something that will only be a fraction of how good the defaults are.  If you find that on a particular routine the profile shows that it's slow, use a better library such as the ones offered by Intel or GNU's complex floating point library.

**Edit:** Don't be afraid of the possible overhead of a complex number library.  The only memory overhead is that of storing the real and imaginary parts together in an object, and the only time overhead is that of actually packing them together.  Both of these actions will be replicated by an implementation you come up with, unless you never really needed complex numbers in the first place.

Comment: Please leave a comment giving a reason for down voting.

Comment: This is a perfectly correct answer that hits the essential targets.

Comment: I didn't downvote ... I agree that I shouldn't reinvent the wheel :) but I didn't downvote.

Comment: How about the overhead of operations with purely real data using complex numbers? Like (a + 0i)*(b+0i) vs  a*b ?

Comment: @mmoment A proper implementation will be aware of this and include the appropriate dispach routines.

Answer (score 3):

> For the parts that do not require complex operations (which is true for most of my extension): wouldn't
>    (a+0i)*(b+0i) be significantly slower than a*b
>   ?

Yes it will (unless you compile with `-ffast-math`, IIRC). But you can simply write:

`a.real() * b.real()`

No need to rewrite `std::complex`, it provides all the methods you need.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I am one of the few people with the opinion that std::complex may, in some critical inner loops, be too slow, but in any case here are my two cents: A while ago I was writing a simple piece of code that evaluates a complex polynomial in three variables and performs some divisions. I noticed that, whenever I replace a complex division (more) or multiplication (less) operator overload (* or /) with the corresponding explicit real-valued algorithms, the code ran noticeably faster. After replacing most of the multiplications and divisions, I believe the speed gain was around 30 to 40 percent. Not an extreme amount, but good enough to warrant reduced readability in such a limited and critical piece of code.

This was on GCC (I do not remember the version, but it was in the 4.x), and I checked the complex division to see why it was so slow. It turned out that it performed many checks for Infs and NaNs to ensure correct behavior in edge cases of the operation. Of course, when doing numerical operations, when you get a NaN, you are lost anyway, so this checking is not really wanted. I did not check whether this checking can be turned off.

Comment: The actual problem with std::complex is that by the standard you can't use it on an arbitrary type, which may be fine or may bite you when you eventually have to use it on your own type (e.g.  the standard gives undefined behaviour for std::complex<std::complex<double> > )

Answer (score 1):

Making your own struct and hand writing the operations won't do anything but make your code harder to read and less maintainable.

What you really want is to harness SSE/AVX instructions in order to speed things up. The best way to do that is to
- Use a library like Intel's MKL (which has a license fee but it is very fast)
- Look at Agner Fog's vector library and his optimization manual
- Research how to write code that the compiler can easily optimize into SSE/AVX instructions

Also worth noting is that these kinds of operations can be sped up a lot through multi-threading which is most easily done either by using a compiler that supports auto-parrallelization with the appropriate directives, or through some OpenMP (a very helpful library to know if you haven't tooled around with it).

Lastly, you can write your own SSE/AVX code through the intrinsic libraries, but this is very time intensive and makes code hard to maintain. Also, unless you are doing some really tricky stuff that can't be easily implemented with something like the MKL, you probably won't get a good speed boost doing this unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

As Randomusername suggests I think do not reinvent the wheel is the best option.

But if the most scenarios is not required use complex operation, why yo do not use a wrapper over std::complex to implement a class for both kinds of number (real and complex one), an object as real number and another complex number using a same interface (with a little overhead for inheritance but good performing thanks to discriminate between real - faster - and complex domain with minimal changes). Better explaining in code:

```
template < typename T>
class number
{
   //operators declarations
   //example
   //virtual number& operator= (const T& val) = 0;
   //virtual number& operator+= (const T& val) = 0;
   //virtual number& operator-= (const T& val) = 0;
   //virtual number& operator*= (const T& val) = 0;
   //virtual number& operator/= (const T& val) = 0;
};
template < typename T>
class real : public number<T>
{
    T number;
   //operators declarations

   // number& operator= (const T& val);
   // number& operator+= (const T& val);
   // number& operator-= (const T& val);
   // number& operator*= (const T& val);
   // number& operator/= (const T& val);
};
template < typename T>
class owncomplex :public number<T>
{
    std::complex<T> _complex;
    //operators declarations

   // number& operator= (const T& val);
   // number& operator+= (const T& val);
   // number& operator-= (const T& val);
   // number& operator*= (const T& val);
   // number& operator/= (const T& val); 
};
```

It is a pretty hard to rewrite any operator but you can use std::complex implementation and improve the real operations with literal operation optimization.